# I want to get the last element and the 3rd to the last element of each line in a .txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what my .txt file contains:

> ECS10 A 4
>
> ECS20 B 3
>
> JPN4 C 5
>
> PHY9A D 5

Here is my program to get the last element of each line:

```
f = open("grade_file.txt", "r")

line = f.readlines()

for i in (line):

    print(i[-1:])
```

For some reason, when it prints each line out, each line has an extra space at the end before it gets to the number (except for the very last line).

So it prints out just a number 5 at the very end because the last line didn't have an extra space. How can I get the last element and the third element to calculate the GPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip the whitespace from the lines before grabbing the last element:

```
f = open("grade_file.txt", "r")
line = f.readlines()

for i in (line):
    i = i.strip()
    print(i[-1:])
```

Answer (score 0):

Humnm this is interesting as I am not getting your results

```
 x='PHY9A D 5'
 >>>> x
  'PHY9A D 5'
```

I personally do not understand how you could get anything but a string by reading lines If I were writing this code I would do the following

```
my_lines = open(r'c:\myfile.txt').readlines()

sum_of_grades = 0

for number_of_courses, line in enumerate(my_lines):
    course, grade, value_for_gpa = line.split()
    sum_of_grades += int(value_for_gpa)

gpa = sum_of_grades/float(number_of_courses)
```